# how to make Ghidra use a function's complete/original stackframe for decompiled code

Tags: reverse-engineering, ghidra

I have a case where some function allocates/uses a 404 bytes temporary structure on the stack for its internal calculations (the function is self-contained and shuffles data around within that data structure). Conceptually the respective structure seems to consist of some 32-bit counters followed by an int[15] and a byte[80] array, and then an area that might or might not actually be used. Some of the generated data in the tables seems to represent offsets that are again used by the function to navigate within the temporary structure.

Unfortunately Ghidra's decompiler makes a total mess while trying to make sense of the function: In particular it creates separate "local_.." int-vars (and then uses a pointer to that var) for what should correctly be a pointer into the function's original data-structure (e.g. pointing into one of the arrays).

```
    undefined4 local_17f;
...
    dest= &local_17f;
    for (i = 0xf; i != 0; i = i + -1) {
      *dest = 0;
      dest = dest + 1;
    }
```

Ghidra does not seem to understand that an array based data access is actually being used at that point. Ghirda's decompiler then also generates a local auStack316[316] variable which unfortunately seems to cover only a part of the respective local data structure used by the original ASM code (at least Ghidra actually did notice that a temporary memory buffer is used). As a result the decompiled code basically uses two overlapping (and broken) shadow data structures that should correctly just be the same block of memory.

Is there some way to make Ghidra's decompiler use the complete 404 bytes block allocated by the function as an auStack404 thus bypassing Ghidra's flawed interpretation logic and actually preserve the original functionality of the ASM code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something.. In the "Listing" view the used local-variable layout is shown as a comment under the function's header. It seems that by right clicking on a respective local-var line in that comment, "set data type" can be applied to a respective local variable. Ah, and then there is what I've been looking for under "Function/"Edit stack frame" :-)